# Cannot resolve android.net.SntpClient class

Tags: android, ntp, grepcode

I am trying to use the class SntpClient that should be in the android.net package, but Android Studio is telling me it cannot find it. Indeed when I look through the source jars (of both API 19 and API 21), the class is not there. However according to grepcode it should be.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/net/SntpClient.java

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Google has chosen not to make all public classes available as part of the SDK. Visibility is controlled by the @hide comment tag [as described here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/net/SntpClient.java/?v=source).

I'm not sure why they chose to hide SntpClient particularly, but provided you respect the terms of the Apache license you can copy the source into your application without much modification.

Comment: Usually I see classes with @hide tag though. This one I can't track down at all, so I guess it's actually missing from the SDK.

Comment: @Flyview Can you give an example of a hidden class that is available in the SDK?

Comment: TelephonyManager.isMultiSimEnabled() is an example. It has the @hide tag but I can still see the method. Maybe it's because that's just a method that's hidden and SntpClient is an entire class that's hidden?

Comment: I can't see isMultiSimEnabled in the intellisense of Eclipse on a TelephonyManager instance so I wonder why it's visible for you? Perhaps there are particular versions of the SDK where it leaked out by accident? I notice it's in curly braces in the Android source, but there's no documentation to suggest that is significant.

Comment: If you click through into TelephonyManager (I'm using Android Studio, so ctrl+click), you can see the whole class, and many methods with the @hide tag.